# Calculating frequency of symbols of binary file in c# not working but working for equivalent c++ code

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, linked-list, binaryfiles

I am trying to calculate the frequency of symbols in a binary file in `c#`, I have already done that in c++ and that works fine and i have switched to c# from c++ because i have to implement the same in c#.

**Note:** I don't have to use LUTs/Arrays only the linkedlist must be used.

By `frequency` i mean number of repetitions of symbols and by `symbols` i mean if we see binary file using `xxd -b BinaryFile.bin` then we will get lot of `8 bits` of combinations of `0` and `1`. So how many times each symbol repeats is it's frequency.

**Now, How i have tried to do so:**
 I achieve it in `c#` by doing `mono filename.exe BinaryFile.bin` at terminal with code written in filename inside notepad++.

**Logic:**
I read each symbol in the BinaryFile if it is not repeated then i add it at the tail of linked list and if it is repeated then i increase it's frequency. This i repeat for full binary file.

**Code:**

Code for c# (full): (which don't work properly, I have pointed the problem containing part in the code, I put full code because may be you will need it):

```
  ////Problem containing part starts here ////////
        public Huffman(string[] args) //called from MyClass 
        {
            Node tree = null;
            int counter = 0;
            using(var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0]))) 
            {
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
                {
                    int processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
                    Node ppt, pt, temp;
                    bool is_there = false;
                    ppt = pt = tree;
                    while (pt != null) 
                    {
                        if (pt.symbol == processingValue) 
                        {
                            pt.freq++;
                            is_there = true;

                            break;
                        }
                        ppt = pt;
                        pt = pt.next;
                    }
                    if (is_there == false) 
                    {
                        temp = new Node();
                        temp.symbol = processingValue;
                        temp.freq = 1;
                        temp.left = null;
                        temp.right = null;
                        temp.next = null;
                        temp.id = (++total_nodes);
                        temp.is_processed = 0;
                        if (tree == null) 
                        {
                            tree = temp;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            ppt.next = temp;
                        }
//The same check/debugging which i was doing in c++ to know what symbol and freq contains but they contains different values. 
//And the output of both c#/c++ are different where as it was supposed to be same.
                        Node chc = tree;
                        while (chc != null) 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("  sym: " + chc.symbol);
                            Console.WriteLine("  freq: " + chc.freq);
                            chc = chc.next;
                        }
                    }
                }
                stream.Close();
            }


        }
 ////Problem containing part Ends here ////////
```

**Difference between the output of the c++ and c#:**

(1) When i display the output of the c++ it works correctly and when i see the code part which i have written in my code to debug/check the output on the terminal for that shows the correct execution of code. whereas the same debugging code in c# don't show the same output with c++. which it was supposed to be do because both of these code to print "symbol" and "freq" are kept at the same place in program.

(2) The output of c# makes me feel that while loop is executed less number of times in c# then in c++ because in c# output terminal don't show large amount repetition of freq and symbol. Please see the output of both :

c# output at terminal :

```
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/$ mono check1.exe out.bin 
  sym: 0
  freq: 1
  sym: 0
  freq: 200
  sym: 1
  freq: 1
  sym: 0
  freq: 200
  sym: 1
  freq: 198
  sym: 2
  freq: 1
  sym: 0
  freq: 200
  sym: 1
  freq: 198
  sym: 2
  freq: 195
  sym: 3
  freq: 1
  sym: 0
  freq: 200
  sym: 1
  freq: 198
  sym: 2
  freq: 195
  sym: 3
  freq: 189
  sym: 4
  freq: 1
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/
```

whereas the output of `c++` is : (here the value of counter actually started form "0" (Not "196") but is not able to show the full output because the file is larger so output is big terminal is not able to show all, it just shows the output at the end)

```
    hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/$ ./filename out.bin

  //Counter starts from "0" but terminal is not able to show all.So doing from "196"
    counter: 196
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  1
    counter: 197
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  2
    counter: 198
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  3
    counter: 199
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  4
    counter: 200
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  5
    counter: 201
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  6
    counter: 202
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  7
    counter: 203
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  8
    counter: 204
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  9
    counter: 205
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  10
    counter: 206
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  11
    counter: 207
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  12
    counter: 208
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  13
    counter: 209
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  14
    counter: 210
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  15
    counter: 211
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  16
    counter: 212
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  17
    counter: 213
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  18
    counter: 214
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  19
    counter: 215
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  20
    counter: 216
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  21
    counter: 217
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  22
    counter: 218
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  23
    counter: 219
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  24
    counter: 220
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  25
    counter: 221
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  26
    counter: 222
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  27
    counter: 223
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  28
    counter: 224
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  29
    counter: 225
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  30
    counter: 226
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  31
    counter: 227
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  32
    counter: 228
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  33
    counter: 229
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  34
    counter: 230
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  35
    counter: 231
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  36
    counter: 232
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  37
    counter: 233
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  38
    counter: 234
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  39
    counter: 235
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  40
    counter: 236
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  41
    counter: 237
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  42
    counter: 238
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  43
    counter: 239
      sym:  0
      freq:  50
      sym:  1
      freq:  50
      sym:  2
      freq:  48
      sym:  3
      freq:  48
      sym:  4
      freq:  44
```

**Questions:**

(1) Why the output shown by c# code is different from c++ ? Even i have tasted on same BinaryFile (out.bin in my case).

(2) Could you please help me in coming out of this problem ? Big thanks

Comment: Your C++ code is awful.
1. You’ve obviously copy-pasted your Node class from some tree implementation (probably an RB tree), and reused them for your lists.
2. Using linked lists for that instead of arrays or hashmaps are extremely ineffective.

Comment: C#: You might change `Node tree = null;` to `tree = null;`

Comment: @DieterLücking , Thanks,I have done it but it still gives the same output.

Comment: @Soonts No it was not a copy paste, I have written a logic there and i am obliged to use Linked list (I am practising pointers). Yes ofcourse i will create huffman tree using this approach once if it is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be totally misunderstanding this... Are you just wanting to know the number of occurrences of each byte value (0..255) within a specified file?

If so, a simple way to do it is like this:

```
var counts = new int[256];  // Assumes files aren't longer than 2GB.

string filename = "<Your filename goes here>";

foreach (byte b in File.ReadAllBytes(filename)) // Will run out of memory
    ++counts[b];                                // for very large files!

for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} occurred {1} times.", i, counts[i]);
```

However, this is so much simpler than what you're doing that I feel I must be misunderstanding....

---

[EDIT]

I can't fix your original code, but here's a sample program that works that uses a linked-list to solve the problem:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public sealed class Node
    {
        public byte Symbol { get; set; }
        public int Count   { get; set; }
        public Node Next   { get; set; }
    }

    sealed class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            var linkedList = new Node();

            string filename = @"C:\Test\t.cs";

            foreach (byte symbol in File.ReadAllBytes(filename))
                addSymbol(symbol, linkedList);

            for (int symbol = 0; symbol < 256; ++symbol)
            {
                int count = countForSymbol((byte)symbol, linkedList);
                Console.WriteLine("Symbol {0} occurred {1} times.", symbol, count);
            }
        }

        private static void addSymbol(byte symbol, Node head)
        {
            Node last = head;

            while (head != null)
            {
                last = head;

                if (head.Symbol == symbol)
                {
                    ++head.Count;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    head = head.Next;
                }
            }

            last.Next = new Node
            {
                Symbol = symbol, 
                Count = 1
            };
        }

        private int countForSymbol(byte symbol, Node head)
        {
            while (head != null)
            {
                if (head.Symbol == symbol)
                    return head.Count;
                else
                    head = head.Next;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. You are right to some extent in understanding me. I am trying to find the frequency of symbols in binary file(number of time it repeats) but i don't have to use arrays/LUTs i have to use linkedlist. I add each symbol in the file. if that symbol read is new then i add it at the end of linked list and read again th next symbol if the new symbol exists in already existing linked list then i increase the "freq" count and if again the new symbol don't exist i add it at the end of Linked List.My C++  code works fine for but i need help in c#.

Comment: could you please give equivalet version in c# (You can take my c++ code and existing c# code as reference). Would be a big help.

Comment: @user234839 to get linked list versio nof that result, simply do `new LinkedList<int>(counts)`.  That should give you a linked list version afterwards.

Comment: @LB2 Thank but i don't have to use anything inbuilt even not LUTs/Arrays.The objective is to learn pointers

Comment: @user234839 I see - this is homework then? I wouldn't use a linked list for this kind of problem at all; you could do what LB2 suggests, but it's kindof cheating ;) And you can't learn about pointers in C# really - it doesn't use them (except in special and unusual circumstances). C# uses references instead.

Comment: Matthew Yes you are right we have references in c# I also know the complexity using LList is more then what you said and "I tried to do that" but i don't know why the output is not expeced.Thats why i have requested for help.

Comment: @user234839 Fair enough - unfortunately your code is too complicated for me to see what is wrong without spending some time running it under a debugger. Have you tried running it under the debugger yourself?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I tried to debug using console.writeline. Actually when i run c++ code the code contains "     printf("  sym:  %d\n", chc -> symbol);
        printf("  freq:  %d\n", chc -> freq)" statments and equivalent code is written to print in c# as well , but the difference between the two is i don't know why this while loop executes very less number of time in c# but it executes correctly in c++(executes for full binary file length). It's my full c# code. You can test for any binary file if you want.

Comment: @MatthewWatson do you think that it is correct that in c# code if you see "  int processingValue = stream.ReadByte();" it returns "integer" does that create any kind of problem(i am using binary reader) ? Because the logic to calculate frequency and to create linked list seems correct , There may be some problem in reading the file (may be any data type is creating problem). Do you think so ?

Comment: @user234839 I see...  I must admit (as Matthew pointed out) that C# is a poor choice to learn pointers, albeit references is a similar concept.

Comment: @LB2 Ok thanks :) i also admit that but i am using reference and i am trying to know why the result in c# and c++ code is not same, Is there is anything wrong in logic(but logic to calculate frequency and creating Linked list seems correct to me), then what is the problem in the code.

Comment: @user234839 Can you please post your out.bin and expected statistics for the file that you get from C++ version?

Comment: @user234839 Re: `int processingValue = stream.ReadByte();` This should be ok because it simply converts an unsigned byte value to an int, but be aware that it returns -1 at end-of-stream.

Comment: @LB2 I have jst edited the question please see the last part of my code, I have explained how to do . Thankyou so much

Comment: @MatthewWatson , Yaah i have noticed what you just said but i have just edited the question please see the last part of my code, I have explained how to do . Thankyou so much

Comment: @MatthewWatson actually your code gives the same output as my code do (when i use BinaryFile.bin instead of "C:\Test\t.cs"). It's not correct, see it's like : Symbol 0 occurred 200 times.
Symbol 1 occurred 198 times.
Symbol 2 occurred 195 times.
Symbol 3 occurred 189 times.
Symbol 4 occurred 180 times.
Symbol 5 occurred 0 times.
Symbol 6 occurred 0 times.
Symbol 7 occurred 0 times.
Symbol 8 occurred 0 times.
 and this repeats until 255.

Comment: @MatthewWatson But the correct output is (which i obtained from c++ file using same binary file): " sym:  0
  freq:  50
  sym:  1
  freq:  50
  sym:  2
  freq:  48
  sym:  3
  freq:  48
  sym:  4
  freq:  44
"  Which i am not able to get. That's why i asked it on stackoverflow. I think there may be anything wrong in our way reading datatypes. Don't you think so?

Comment: @user234839 You really need to define what the output should be more clearly... It's somewhat ambiguous. The code I posted works correctly for determining the number of occurrences of each of the possible 256 byte values within a file. If this is not what you are looking for, you must define what you want instead.

Comment: For example, given a binary file containing the 256 byte values from 00h to FFh repeated 100 times, what should the results be? My code will give a count of 100 for each "symbol".